# How to use subqueries in sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, kohana, sphinx

Here is the code of sphinx

```
    $sphinx_results = clone $this->sphinx;

    //Select Columns
    $sphinx_results->SetSelect($col . ', @count'); //Select cols

    //Group results
if($col=='province')
{
    $sort_str = ($sort_str === FALSE) ? $col.' asc' : $sort_str; //Get sort string
    }
else
$sort_str = ($sort_str === FALSE) ? '@count desc' : $sort_str; //Get sort string
$sphinx_results->SetGroupBy($col, $sphinx_results::SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR, $sort_str);

    //Perform Query
    $results = $sphinx_results->Query( $this->keyword, 'autoandt_www' );
```

I wanted to select 10 provinces with maximum count and i wanted to this result in alphabetical order of provinces. How to accomplish this in php sphinx. I am using kohana framework.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just get the top 10 results from sphinx - which it looks like you already have that in your code.

Then in the *application* resort them into alphabetical order. Pretty trivial in most languages. within PHP the `uksort` function is nice. But no idea if kohana provides any sort of convenience function.

Comment: I couldnt even find the basics for sphinx in php with examples. Can you share the site that has some examples.

Comment: what site? I don't know what one you are talking about. but can offer this http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example.php

Comment: I mean any tutorials with examples?